# flutter gesturedector on tap doesn't work with PopupMenubutton

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

GestureDetector's ontap is not working with PopupMenuButton. I would like to change the direction when tapping PopupMenuButton, but as gestureDetector's ontap is not triggered, I can't change it.

I've checked that ontap works in PopupMenuButton's onSelected or onCanceled, but that's not what I wanted to do because it doesn't change arrow direction tapping the area that should be triggered.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Get.find<HomeController>();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Obx(
          () => GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onTapDown: (detail) {
              print('tap');
              print(detail.globalPosition.dx);
              controller.handlePopupMenuArrowIcon(); // it doesn't work all the time when I tap. sometimes works, sometimes doens't work
            },
            child: PopupMenuButton<String>(
              offset: Offset(0, 38),
              shape: TooltipShape(),
              onSelected: (String where) {
                controller.changeLocation(where);
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                return [
                  PopupMenuItem(value: 'ara', child: Text('아라동')),
                  PopupMenuItem(value: 'ora', child: Text('오라동')),
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    value: 'setting_neighborhood',
                    child: Text('내 동네 설정하기'),
                  ),
                ];
              },
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    controller.locationTypeToString[
                        controller.currentLocation.value]!,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  controller.openOtherLocal.value
                      ? Icon(
                          Icons.keyboard_arrow_up_rounded,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )
                      : Icon(
                          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 1.0,
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use showMenu instead:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Hope it's helpful for you :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @聂超群. I think I need to use PopupMenuItem to use onSelected method to select location and get the location's data. I applied onTapDown with it and it seems working, but it's not triggered all the time. But there is a flaw like if I tap PopupMenuItem long like 1 sec, the arrow icon is changed and with quick tap it doenn't work. What is wrong with it? I edited my codes.

Comment: Do you mean onTapDown wasn't triggered every time?

Comment: No, it wasn't triggered every time. it is triggered when I tap longer than like 0.5 sec? If i just tap in real, click mouse quickly, it is not triggered every time. Actually, arrow icon should be changed whenever PopMenuItem open and close, upside and downside... Um... it should be the out of the question though... Maybe my approach to implement what I wanted wasn't correct..?

Comment: Because PopupMenuButton's implementation include touch event, maybe there are event conflict somewhere, which cause your problem. I suggest you remove PopupMenuButton, use showMenu instead, which will complete your task.

Comment: I need to change location with onSelected of PopupMenuButton and get data depends on the location. I think there is no such method like onSelected in showMenu... 

Comment: Can add onTap on PopMenuItem fulfill your requirement?

Comment: I tried adding onTap on PopMenuItem,then I got an error 'The argument type 'List<GestureDetector>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<PopupMenuEntry<dynamic>>'.', onTap doesn't take any argument so, the widget never knows which location I select.